# Strange behavior casting to Integer

Tags: php

I'm trying to do some very simple math and for a specific set of numbers, it just isn't coming out right.

This is for a WooCommerce payment gateway.  First, I get the cart total, which should be a float but for some weird reason got reported as a string in my debug code, so I forced it into a float just to be safe.  Then I get the subunits, which is an Integer.  I feel like multiplying a Float and an Int should be fine but anyway, I cast it because this was giving me so many problems.  Then, I multiply them.  Finally, I cast it to Integer as it should be a whole number anyway.

FWIW, subunits is always `100`, so the result should be expressing a 2-decimal amount as an integer.  `54.99` should be `5499`, `12.50` should be `1250`, and so on.  This simple math always works, *except* when the total is `66.10`, which always gives me `6609` for some reason.

```
    $total = floatval($this->order->get_total());
    $subunits = floatval($this->number_of_subunits_in_currency);
    $amount = $total * $subunits;
    $amount_int = intval($amount);
    WC_Gateway_XXX::log( sprintf( __( '$total is %f(%s), and $subunits is %f(%s).  the float product is %f(%s) and the intval is %u(%s)', 'flywire-payment-gateway' ), $total, gettype($total), $subunits, gettype($subunits), $amount, gettype($amount), $amount_int, gettype($amount_int) ) );

    // Serialize order info into JSON
    $settings                 = array();
    $settings['amount']       = $amount_int;

    WC_Gateway_XXX::log( sprintf( __( '$settings[\'amount\'] is %u(%s)', 'xxx-payment-gateway' ), $settings['amount'], gettype($settings['amount']) ) );
```

When I run the above code, I get the follow debug logs:

`$total is 66.100000(double), and $subunits is 100.000000(double).  the float product is 6610.000000(double) and the intval is 6609(integer)`

`$settings['amount'] is 6609(integer)`

For all other numbers, it works.  But for some reason, it's calculating the intval of `6610.000000` as `6609`.

Answer (score -1):

floats are notoriously unreliable, and casting a float to an int leaves all sorts of options open to the interpreter. you're forcing a square peg into a round hole and asking the system to do its best, really. Instead, you could take control of how you want it.
e.g. How about multiplying by 100 and truncating?